# Get array from json using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Server returns me such object, but i need only array ITEMS.
How can i get it?
I tried `array['items']` but the result is `undefiend`

```
{
   "items": [
    {
      ..
    },
    {
      ..
    },
    {
      ..
    }
  ],.. 
  ,..
}
```

Comment: Is the server responding with JSON or a string of JSON?

Comment: this is endpoints. the GAE somehow convert java object to js object

Comment: Could you post more of the code? From what you've posted so far, it looks like what you're trying to do should work.

Comment: well. thanks. i get what was the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// JSON string returned from the server
var text = '{"items":[{"name":"itemX" ,"price":15},{"name":"itemY","price":25},{"name":"itemZ","price":20}]}';

// Convert the string returned from the server into a JavaScript object.
var object = JSON.parse(text);

// Accessing a specific property value of an item
console.log(object.items[0].name); //itemX

// Extract 'items' in to a separate array
var itemsArray = object.items;
console.log(itemsArray); //[itemObject, itemObject, itemObject]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting this as a string:

```
var json = JSON.parse(my_json_string)
```

Then,

```
var keys = Object.keys(json);
var values = [];
for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
    values.push(json[keys[i]]);
}
```